# wordpress mobile responsive is not working correctly

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress- theme salient. It already has media queries for mobile responsive that go from:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width :     1024px) {}
```

As you can see it covers the widths from phones to tablets. Our developers do not wish to alter this default code in the global css where it lives, but we need to make the site responsive for phones and tablets in separate queries on the individual page's css. I would like the phone to have a max-width of 480px, the tablet to have a max width of 1024, and the desktop to have a max of 2000.

What is the correct order and syntax for the three media queries that I should make? When I try to place the queries into the site they do not listen to me even when I use !important. I have been doing my research and have learned that it is better practice to start from mobile and go up to desktop, but again, I am using wordpress which starts out with the desktop version.

Any suggestions will be very appreciated!Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do 3 media rules i something Luke this

```
 /** here goes the common parte of      the style **/

/**Start of @media **/
/** Desktop Rules **/
@media (min-device-width : 1025px) {} 
/**Tablet Rules **/
@media (max-device-width : 1024px) {}
/** Mobile Rules**/
 @media (max-device-width : 480px) {}
```

Sorry for bad layout, I'm from mobile. And welcome ti stackoverflow ;)